# 200/'parsererror' with jquery on ajax post to a https

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've read loads of other questions about this argument, but none could solve my problem.
I make a call to a php page in this way.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://mydomain/page.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            "arg1": arg1,
            "arg2": arg2
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            //do stuff
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            alert("doLogin\n- readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\n- status: "+xhr.status);
        }
    });
```

Now, if I put this stuff on the same server as the php it works fine. Troubles start when I launch it from localhost.
In that case I receive the following in the xhr:
`readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"`.
Reading some answers on the topic it seems to be because of a same-origin restriction, so I added a few parameters to the call. notably:

```
   dataType:"jsonp",
   crossDomain: true,
```

Apparently this works better, cause now I receive `readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success"`. Trouble is, `textStatus="parsererror"`. I also tried other things as `jsonpCallback`, `cache`, `async`, `jsonp` in many configurations with no luck.

Now, I receive no data back, cause this call will only give me a cookie that I need.

My question is: am I doing things correctly, for starters? In both cases, what is the reason of such an error? Does the fact that I call a 'https'/POST change something, rather than a plain http/GET?

Second question is, later on I will have to call some webservices through soap requests, which will return data in xml. Will using this same technique work (assuming jQuery doc is fine and I can write `dataType:"jsonp xml"` to have it converted on the fly (and assuming it is the right technique as well))? I assume it won't be, as jsonp expects something on the line of `callbackFN({...})` rather than an xml, right?

If none of this is correct, what would the correct way to proceed be? I can't touch the server, thus I am limited to client side.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `dataType` as `JSONP`, you can only get data as JSON.

So if the url (https://mydomain/page.php) doesn't response a JSON object, you will get parsing error, because it tries to parse it and fails.

Comment: Why do the docs then say: _"As of jQuery 1.5, [...] You can also make a JSONP request, have it received as text, and interpreted by jQuery as XML: "jsonp text xml." Similarly, a shorthand string such as "jsonp xml" will first attempt to convert from jsonp to xml, and, failing that, convert from jsonp to text, and then from text to xml. "_
If I put `dataType:"jsonp text"` it sould work, cause it would treat it as text, is that correct? I still get the same error, though.

Comment: I didn't know that we can use multiple dataType for jsonp, have just learnt it. But that seems impossible, because jsonp request has a different request type. And actually I have never seen a simple which worked like that. And a suggestion-> you can use [yql](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is for JSON format data only! So if you receive a parseerror this means that the output of your PHP might not be well-formed JSON

And no, it is not easily possible to have XML as response to a JSONP call ..

Comment: How would you go with it, then? Any way to get that xml back without setting up a proxy, that you'd know?

Comment: I admit that the docs say that using datatype:"jsonp xml" should be possible. But the docs also give no details ... even other stackoverflow topics didn't cover it yet ... interesting